# Methodchannel is not calling from background service onStart in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-method-channel

I want to fetch data from native side to flutter in background service call. I have implemented [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) to work with foreground and background tasks at flutter side.

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
  service.setAsForegroundService();
});
service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
  service.setAsBackgroundService();
});
}service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
service.stopSelf();
});
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) async {
if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
      print('FLUTTER FOREGROUND SERVICE: ${DateTime.now()}');
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      try {
        await bgMethodChannel.invokeMethod(bgMethod);
      } catch (e) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("EXCEPTION: $e");
        }
      }
    }
}
});
}
```

print statement is getting printed in every 5 seconds in foreground but method channel call is throwing exception : MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method bg_method on channel inhalerChannelBG)

await bgMethodChannel.invokeMethod(bgMethod);

this line is working everywhere else but not inside onStart. I have used it calling in main() , that gives me results from android native side.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hello @shriya, did you find any alternative way to fix this?

Comment: `flutter_background_service` is breaking many plugins in Flutter. I am experiencing it with SpotifySDK and getting the same `MissingPluginException` in iOS only, Android working fine. I think they are using the same channel/event that's why...

Answer (score 0):

try to change the type of the `onStart` method from `void` to `Future<void>` and call it like this `await onStart(...)` to make sure that it is fully initialized.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
But I am using onStart in service configurations so can't use await here.


  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: true,
      onForeground: onStart,
    ),
  );

Comment: It didn't work @mohamedaminehnioua

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been [solved](https://github.com/ekasetiawans/flutter_background_service/issues/138) by adding `DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();` after this line `void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {`

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized(); //add this 
if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
  service.setAsForegroundService();
});
service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
  service.setAsBackgroundService();
});
}service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
service.stopSelf();
});
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) async {
if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
      print('FLUTTER FOREGROUND SERVICE: ${DateTime.now()}');
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      try {
        await bgMethodChannel.invokeMethod(bgMethod);
      } catch (e) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("EXCEPTION: $e");
        }
      }
    }
}
});
}
```

Comment: It does not work with DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized(); 

Can you tell me what could i change at native android side to access it through method channel.

Comment: I see. Could you share your `pubspec.yaml` please? Since you are using android for your background service, have you added one of the [dependencies](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service_android)?

Answer (score 0):

create a plugin. search over official docs for how to. the plugins get registered automatically with new flutter engine that gets invoked in this onstart(separate isolate).using the method channels defined in this plugin you can talk with native code successfully, I have tested it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).